# Have custom manager but keep objects keyword available

Tags: python, django, django-1.8

I am learning Python + Django (basically in love - 100% .NET guy before), and I am trying to learn the concept of managers.

I am trying to add a custom manager called `ProviderManager`, which will get some objects depending on some input.

However, I still want to be able to say stuff like:

```
city= City.objects.filter(id = city_id).first()
```

Inside my `views.py` file.

I do understand that when I add a new custom manager, it will override the objects keyword.

However, my question then is: how do I both have the objects available, but also my new provider method, so I can say `City.provider.get_provider()` ?

**Current code:**

```
class ProviderManager(models.Manager):

    def get_provider(country, city=0):
        return "abekat"


class City(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, null=True)
    is_visible = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    providers = ProviderManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**Views.py:**

```
def city(request, country_id, city_id):
    country= Country.objects.filter(id = country_id).first()
    city= City.objects.filter(id = city_id).first()
    print city

    data = {
            'country': country.title,
            'city': city.title,
            'provider': 'abe',
        }

    return render(request, 'city.html', data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managers provide Methods for table-wide operations (referring to the table of the model they are added to).
So if you want to write a manager for your City model it would be best pratice to call it CityManager.

Since custom managers inherit from models.Manager, you can overwrite the objects name in your model class. This won't change the behaviour of the standard objects manager, but your custom methods will also be available under the objects name.

See the documentation for more details:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers

And please pay attention to the distinction between Managers and Model methods,latter ones are for "row-level" functionality as explainded in the documentation.